# How to make the width of select2 show full?

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-select2

How to make the width of select2 show full?

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ __('Pages') }}</label>
  <select name="item[{{ $reasonItem['id'] }}][page]" class="form-control col-sm-10 select2" required>
    <option value="">{{ __('Choose') }}</option>
      @foreach($pages as $key=>$val)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ (($key == ($reasonItem['page'] ?? '') ) ? "selected":"") }}>{{$val}}</option>
      @endforeach
  </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Select2 will do its best to resolve the percent width specified via a **CSS class**, but it is not always possible. The best way to ensure that Select2 is using a percent based width is to **inline** the style declaration into the tag. https://select2.org/appearance#container-width so change to `<select name="item[{{ $reasonItem['id'] }}][page]" class="form-control col-sm-10 select2" style="width : 100%" required>`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<select name="item[{{ $reasonItem['id'] }}][page]" class="form-control col-sm-10 select2" style="width:100%" required>
```

It will be work, I checked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
.select2.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I'll suggest you to use the debugger and see what's going on. I've used select2 tens of times and can guarantee you this css styling works - http://joxi.ru/1A5KEy0HzVwOwm

Answer (score 0):

Add `w-auto` class or `w-100` if Bootstrap 5

```
class="form-control col-sm-10 select2 w-auto"
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I'm using bootstrap 4.3